# X doesn't work after upgrading Slackware from 13.37 to 14.0

Tags: kde, upgrade, slackware

I upgraded the system, using instructions from file UPGRADE.txt on the disk. Everything works fine. But when I try to `startx`, it quits with an error:

> ck-launch-session: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.5:
>   cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

In `/usr/lib` I found a file `libffi.so.6`. It seems, that the `ck-launch-session` wasn't upgraded and still tries to load the old library.

What to do?

Comment: I've never used Slackware, but this sounds like a classic dependency problem.  Install libffi 5?  Or did the upgrade to the latest version of ck-launch-session just get missed somehow?

Comment: BTW: what have you used for upgrading? `slackpkg` or something else (e.g. `swaret`)?

Comment: @peterph I used upgradepkg

Comment: A package manager like `slackpkg` or `swaret` would be preferred I guess. At least the former one can for example install any new packages (those that were not present in the repo before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. reinstall both libffi and ConsoleKit packages (update your repository copy first if you have a local clone).
2. uninstall ConsoleKit - strictly speaking it's not necessary (although it provides some level of user comfort and friendliness).
3. symlink `libffi.so.5` to `libffi.so.6` - dirty hack that **might** work, but also may cause **lots** of troubles, **even fatal ones**.

You may also want to consider switching to the rolling versions release - slackware-current.

Comment: dirty hack is really bad. Cause names of functions and parameter have probably changed in the new version.

Comment: @user4035 "**even fatal ones**" is there for a reason. :) It is a last resort, if you can't do anything else and desperately need to run in the set configuration. On the other hand it often works since version upgrades may be just API extension (i.e. backwards compatible) - speaking from experience here. So it's not *bad* - it's *dirty*.

Comment: I double checked the modules on Slackware disk: uninstalled and installed again. I did everything correctly. The modules, provided by Slackware 14, were incompatible. ConsoleKit required libffi5, while libffi6 was on disk. I installed libffi5 from the Internet. And now everything works. Thx!

Comment: Yes the repositories are slightly inconsistent from tiime to time. You may also install ConsoleKit from slackware-current. But if libffi5 doesn't conflict with libffi6 having both is fine I guess.